# How to combine summarize and summarize_if in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to combine a `summarize` statement (to count the number of observations) with a `summarise_if` statement (to summarise all numeric variables).

Using `data("iris")`, I would like to:

1. Count the number of observations per Species and add this count as a column in the new table.
2. Summarise all numeric variables (`Sepal.Length`,`Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`) by `Species`.

I can do these steps separately with the code below:

Number 1.

```
iris %>% 
 group_by(Species)%>% 
 summarise(n = n())
```

Number 2.

```
iris %>% 
 group_by(Species)%>% 
 summarise_if(is.numeric, median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

**Q: How to combine these calculations into one step?**

Just piping one after the other gives me a different result. My desired output is this:

[image]

Comment: `summarise_if` has been superceded by `across` in the latest versions of `dplyr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `across`:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), across(where(is.numeric), median, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

For those interested, the same thing in `data.table`:

```
setDT(iris)
iris[, j = data.frame(n = .N, lapply(.SD, median, na.rm = TRUE)),
     .SDcols = names(iris)[sapply(iris, is.numeric)],
     by = Species]
```